# Just required horizontal swipe event and ignore other events to layout in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to do some tasks by just swiping left to right and right to left. It is working using the below code, but I want to stop getting event from the view like swipe up or down or click event. So, I can get click events for the view below it.

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context=".ui.home.activity.DashboardActivity">

 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_home"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_dashboard"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_dashboard" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/homePageLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_53sdp"
        android:background="@color/cardBackgroundColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
        app:itemBackground="@color/cardBackgroundColor"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/_22sdp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector_text"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nav_host_dashboard"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_dashboard" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

and here I handle

```
binding.homePageLayout.setOnTouchListener(object :
        OnSwipeTouchListener(this@DashboardActivity) {
        override fun onSwipeRight() {
            super.onSwipeRight()
            if (currentPage != R.id.nav_chats) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.nav_chats)
            }
        }

        override fun onSwipeLeft() {
            if (currentPage == R.id.nav_chats) {
                navController.navigate(previousPage)
            }
        }
    })
```

OnSwipeTouchListener is you can find in all places, but anything is required to modify, I mention here

```
internal open class OnSwipeTouchListener(context: Context?) :
OnTouchListener {
private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector

companion object {
    private const val SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100
    private const val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100
}

init {
    gestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, GestureListener())
}

open fun onSwipeLeft() {}
open fun onSwipeRight() {}
override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
}

private inner class GestureListener : SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onFling(
        e1: MotionEvent,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        val distanceX = e2.x - e1.x
        val distanceY = e2.y - e1.y
        if (abs(distanceX) > abs(distanceY) && abs(distanceX) > Companion.SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && abs(
                velocityX
            ) > Companion.SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
        ) {
            if (distanceX > 0) onSwipeRight() else onSwipeLeft()
            return true
        }
        return false
     }
  }
}
```

So, there are different views in different fragments that are not getting click events. and setting swipelistener to topmost ConstraintLayout and even directly fragment also not working, that is why I have setup RelativeLayout. and it is giving swipe events but blocking other views events. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have applied touchlistener to topmost ConstraintLayout and applied codes as below:

```
private lateinit var onSwipeTouchListener: OnSwipeTouchListener

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private fun handleHorizontalSwipe() {

    onSwipeTouchListener = object :
        OnSwipeTouchListener(this@DashboardActivity) {
        override fun onSwipeRight() {
            super.onSwipeRight()
            if (currentPage != R.id.nav_chats) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.nav_chats)
            }
        }

        override fun onSwipeLeft() {
            if (currentPage == R.id.nav_chats) {
                navController.navigate(previousPage)
            }
        }
    }

    binding.homePageLayout.setOnTouchListener(onSwipeTouchListener)

}
 
 // this made it work
 override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    onSwipeTouchListener.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}
```

and no need for an extra view as RelativeLayout as I did.